# How to PushViewController From modalViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have `FavouriteViewController` in which i have one button on click of button i am presenting a view modally called `LoginViewController` (using storyboard)

On this page(`LoginViewController`), i again have button, on click of that i want to push my view controller.

Is it possible ?

Comment: This would result in an unusual UI experience. But if you want to push from any viewcontroller the base viewcontroller has to be embedded in a `UINavigationController`. You could simply try embedding your `LoginViewController`: select it in IB, click Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. But please rethink your UI first since this doesn't look like a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below code.. It may help you to get your desired solution.

1) Present `LoginViewController` by write below code.

```
    LoginViewController *login = [[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login]autorelease];
    nc.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

2) Now from `LoginViewController`, You can push your `MyviewController` as below.

```
    MyviewController *adss = [[[MyviewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyviewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:adss animated:YES];
```

Comment: It crashes app shows: `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller`

Comment: 1st code you need to write in `FavouriteViewController` to present `LoginViewController`.. Are you doing same?

Comment: screen turns out black nothing appears after writnig this `CRLoginWithViewController *login = [[CRLoginWithViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
    nc.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:Nil];`

Comment: You are not using .xib files?

Comment: No i am not using .xib files, still same problem

Comment: Have you created any view inside the `-(id)init` method?

Answer (score 2):

using **UINavigationController**

```
 UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.LoginViewController];
 [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

after this you can push any view controller from presented view controller(LoginViewController)

Comment: This is how to present a modal view controller. OP wants to push viewcontroller from modally presented viewcontroller. (i think)

Comment: He is presenting modally a `UINavigationController`, this is a possible answer :)

Comment: if you think so than you can upward my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This will actually push a VC at the parent and not at the presented VC